# В c# определить переменную условной компиляции в другом проекте

Tags: c#, visual-studio, condition-variable

Можно ли в `c#`, `visualstudio` определить переменную условной компиляции в другом проекте?

Например, есть 2 сборки: `ProjectA`, `ProjectB`, причем `ProjectA` ссылается на `ProjectB`.

В `ProjectB` есть такой код:

```
#if ABC

Console.WriteLine("если отобразилось значит ABC определена");

#endif
```

Можно ли `ABC` определить в `ProjectA`, чтобы отобразилась строчка?

Comment: Почему не использовать что-то времени исполнения, а не времени компиляции?

Comment: Можно, спасибо за совет!

Comment: Пишут, что нельзя так: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5149351/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, но там же и практически workaround дают с targets

Comment: И еще один в конце стэка

Comment: Я до конца не дочитал :Р

Comment: :) 'я вообще не читал, но мнение имею..' :)